# Exception escapes from workflow despite TryCatch activity

Tags: c#, transactions, .net-4.0, workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4

I have a workflow inside a Windows Service that is a loop that performs work periodically. The work is done inside a [`TryCatch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.statements.trycatch.aspx) activity. The [`Try`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.statements.trycatch.try.aspx) property is a [`TransactionScope`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.statements.transactionscope.aspx) activity that wraps some custom activities that read and update a database. When the transaction fails, I would expect any exception that caused this to be caught by the `TryCatch`. However, my workflow aborts. The workflow I have is the following:

```
var wf = new While(true)
{
    Body = new Sequence
    {
        Activities =
        {
            new TryCatch
            {
                Try = new TransactionScope
                {
                    IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted,
                    Body = new Sequence
                    {
                        Activities = { ..custom database activities.. }
                    },
                    AbortInstanceOnTransactionFailure = false
                },
                Catches =
                {
                    new Catch<Exception>
                    {
                        Action = new ActivityAction<Exception>
                        {
                            Argument = exception,
                            Handler = ..log error..
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            new Delay { Duration = new InArgument<TimeSpan>(duration) }
        }
    },
}
```

In my case, it's possible that the database is sometimes unavailable so obviously the transaction won't commit. What happens in this case is that the workflow aborts with the following exception:

> System.OperationCanceledException: An error processing the current work item has caused the workflow to abort.

The inner exception is:

> System.Transactions.TransactionException: The operation is not valid for the state of the transaction.

This makes sense because I have just switched off the database. However, why isn't this exception handled by my `TryCatch` activity?

**EDIT 1**: Some additional information. I run the workflow using the [`WorkflowApplication`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.workflowapplication.aspx) class. To better see what's going on, I specified the properties [`Aborted`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.workflowapplication.aborted.aspx) and [`OnUnhandledException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.workflowapplication.onunhandledexception.aspx). When the exception occurs, it goes directly to `Aborted` and `OnUnhandledException` is skipped (although this is clearly an unhandled exception).

**EDIT 2**: I enabled the debug log and this provides some additional insight. The 'custom database activities' successfully run to completion. The first event log entry that indicates that something is wrong is a Verbose level message: *The runtime transaction has completed with the state 'Aborted'*. Next I see an Information message: *WorkflowInstance Id: 'dbd1ba5c-2d8a-428c-970d-21215d7e06d9' E2E Activity* (not sure what this means). And the Information message after that is: *Activity 'System.Activities.Statements.TransactionScope', DisplayName: 'Transaction for run immediately checks', InstanceId: '389' has completed in the 'Faulted' state*.

After this message, I see that each parent (including the `TryCatch` activity) completes in the 'Faulted' state, ending with the abortion of my workflow.

**EDIT 3**: To be clear, everything works as expected when an exception occurs in any of the 'custom database activities'. The exception is caught and the workflow continues. It only goes wrong when the transaction can't commit at the end of the `TransactionScope`. See the following stacktrace that is logged from the `Aborted` callback:

```
at System.Transactions.TransactionStateInDoubt.Rollback(InternalTransaction tx, Exception e)
at System.Transactions.Transaction.Rollback(Exception e)
at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.CompleteTransactionWorkItem.HandleException(Exception exception)
```

If you follow the calls from `TransactionScope.OnCompletion(...)`, eventually you will arrive at the `ActivityExecutor` class from the stacktrace.

Comment: Just a guess, but perhaps you need to catch a `TransactionException`, instead of `Exception`.

Comment: I'll try add some more catches with more specific exception types but I would expect that catching a generic `Exception` would deal with all exceptions..

Comment: Adding more specific catch statements didn't work. I get the same result: the workflow aborts.

Comment: Are you using the SqlWorkflowInstanceStore? and is it using the same database?

Comment: I have no `InstanceStore` configured for this workflow so it's not persisted. I have found some additional info by enabling the debug log. I'll add this to the question.

Comment: The trace log isn't showing any of the activities in the Catch block? And is the Aborted or Completed callback firing?

Comment: None of the activities in the Catch block is executed and the Aborted callback is firing. In the trace log there are four messages *X has completed in 'Faulted' state*: for `TransactionScope`, `TryCatch`, `Sequence` and `While`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Transactions commit asynchronously and after the fact.  You can't react to a failure of the transaction to commit because of a problem at the resource manager level.

As you pointed out, you can deal with exceptions that occur in your activities.  If you look at the tracking records for your workflow my guess is that you would see the TryCatch activity is closed prior to the transaction abort.

Many years ago when I was a program manager in the COM+ team I studied this issue because often people want a transactional component (or workflow) as in this case to be able to react to a transaction abort.

The async nature of the resolution of the transaction means that you simply cannot react to it in the component itself.  The solution is to react in the caller which can then take some action.

The design assumption is that once a transaction has aborted, nothing about state aqcuired in the transaction can be safely used - it will all be discarded because the transaction is aborted.

Comment: Interesting. I'm not convinced this is the actual problem, however. I actually do not see my TryCatch activity closing before the transaction abort. However, I took another look at what happens when the TransactionScope activity completes. It appears to queue a `CompleteTransactionWorkItem`. This indicates that something asynchronous is going on. However, this must also mean that at some point in time, the workflow thread and the transaction thread join to give me back the stacktrace I posted. I do not see this happening anywhere (I can't even find another thread dequeueing work items).

Comment: Actually what happens is that once the transaction fails the workflow terminates immediately (this is why the try/catch does not close).  If you were able to invoke code in the workflow when the transaction is aborting you might inadvertantly do something with state created under the transaction that is failing.  This violates the isolation semantic of the transaction so it is not allowed.

Comment: Ok, I understand. But it seems a little counter-intuitive to have a `TryCatch` that doesn't actually catch something I expected to be caught. So when using a `TransactionScope` inside a workflow, you have to carefully consider what you want the behavior to be when the transaction aborts. I should probably just go check out some more Endpoint.tv shows :)

Answer (score 2):

So just to add to Ron's answer. Your only option here is to add the SqlWorkflowInstanceStore and drop a Persist activity just before the TransactionScope. When the transaction aborts the whole workflow will abort but the past saved state will still be in the persistence database and the workflow can be restarted from this previously saved state and execute the transaction again.

Comment: I understand this solves my problem but it seems a bit of a workaround... And I still do not have a definitive answer to why the `TryCatch` doesn't catch this specific exception. Is Ron's answer correct? The reason my `TryCatch` doesn't catch the exception that is generated when the transaction tries to complete, is that this happens asynchronously?

Comment: Ron knows his transactional coding. So this isn't a workaround, this is how it has been designed to work. I must admit not exactly what I would have expected or very intuitive but that said using the SqlWorkflowInstanceStore is a normal way of error handling/retrying in WF4.